# SSH keys in build environment when using multibranch pipeline Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, jenkins, ssh, pip

I have a project being built on Jenkins using the multibranch pipeline plugin. I am using the declarative pipeline syntax and my Jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'blah' }
    options {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    triggers { pollSCM('H/5 * * * *') }
    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                  echo "Building environment"
                  python3 -m venv venv && \
                  pip install git+ssh://git@my_private_repo.git
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the build is run on the Jenkins box the build fails and when I check the console output it is failing on the pip install command with the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I am guessing that I need to set the required ssh key into jenkins build environment, but am not sure how to do this.

Comment: this sounds like you don't have access to whatever repo you are trying copy. have you set up the necessary `config` file in your `.ssh` directory on your Jenkins box?

Comment: I guess not. I am trying to convert a job with was running on a single pipeline (without jenkinsfile) to a multibranch pipeline with Jenkinsfile. In the original job it used the config for the job and had the ssh key specified under the section build environment -> ssh-agent. There is no option for this with the multibranch pipeline job, and no doc on how to do it in jenkinsfile

Comment: Put the private key at `~jenkinsuser/.ssh/id_rsa` on the host

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the [SSH Agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent) and use it to wrap the actions in the `steps` directive in order to be able to pull from a private repository. You enable the SSH Agent with the `sshagent` directive, where you need to pass in an argument representing the hash for a valid key with read permissions to the git repository. The key needs to be available in the global credentials view of Jenkins (Jenkins -> Credentials [on the left-hand side menu], search for the ID field of the right key), e.g.:

```
    stage('Prepare') {
        steps {
            sshagent(['<hash_for_your_key>']) {
                echo "Building environment"
                sh "python3.5 -m venv venv"
                sh "venv/bin/python3.5 venv/bin/pip install git+ssh://git@my_private_repo.git
            }
        }
```

N.B.: Because the actions under the `steps` directive are executed as subprocesses, you'll need to call explicitly the executable files from the virtual environment, using long syntax.